# I try to divide two functions from each other and get 0 every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have the code underneat in Amazone Athena to calculate how the last 7 days in footfall compare to the average week last year.
I only get a 0 as a result all the time, what is the problem.
I tried to make the x and y as Float but that still gave zero's
The data is on daily basis and a calculate a week average of last year by addding all weeks and divide by 52 (probably also a better way to do this)

```
select x.visitors/y.visitors*100
from
(select sum(visitors) as visitors
from corrected_scanners_per_day 
where btcode in ('BT120031', 'BT120000','BT902', 'BT120052', 'BT120050', 'BT130109', 'BT120131', 'BT130110', 'BT130107', 'BT120126', 'BT120078', 'BT120076', 'BT120035', 'BT130450', 'BT120063', 'BT120044', 'BT120082', 'BT120030', 'BT120116', 'BT121196', 'BT130366', 'BT120085', 'BT120053', 'BT120014')
And datetime
    BETWEEN current_date - interval '7'day
        AND current_date) x
Join
(select sum(visitors) / 52 as visitors, year(datetime) as year
from corrected_scanners_per_day 
where btcode in ('BT120031', 'BT120000','BT902', 'BT120052', 'BT120050', 'BT130109', 'BT120131', 'BT130110', 'BT130107', 'BT120126', 'BT120078', 'BT120076', 'BT120035', 'BT130450', 'BT120063', 'BT120044', 'BT120082', 'BT120030', 'BT120116', 'BT121196', 'BT130366', 'BT120085', 'BT120053', 'BT120014')
And datetime
    BETWEEN CAST('2019-01-01' AS timestamp)
        AND CAST('2019-12-31' AS timestamp)
group by year(datetime)
order by year(datetime)) y on 1=1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your data types (visitors and 100) are all INT, so your output data type will also be an INT. When the calculation is converted to an INT, it is probably rounding to 0. So you need to explicitly make sure your final data type is a numeric type that allows decimals.
Try changing the first line to this:

`select (x.visitors * 1.0) / (y.visitors * 1.0) * 100.0`

You have other INT types inside your subqueries that should also probably be converted to decimals to make sure no truncation or rounding is occurring.